# OkHttp Cookies with domains that start with a dot

Tags: android, xamarin.android, okhttp

Within a Xamarin app we are having a problem on Android where OkHttp is failing to send requests if they contain cookies where the domain starts with a dot.

```
Exception:     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Ex. Message:   unexpected domain: .direct.aviva.co.uk

Original stack trace:
======================
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : unexpected domain: .my.domain.com
        at okhttp3.Cookie$Builder.domain(Cookie.kt:297)
        at okhttp3.Cookie$Builder.domain(Cookie.kt:287)
```

As far as I'm aware its valid for a domain to start with a dot but in the past this potentially wasn't allowed, is this correct? Could it be newer versions of OkHttp wouldn't throw this error?

We are using OkHttp 4.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re constructing the cookie object programmatically, just omit the leading dot. That’s the rule according to the spec that OkHttp implements.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-5.2.3

Comment: Unfortunately we aren't building it programmatically, its coming from a Set Cookie header. We've been informed by the producers of the tool that is requesting the cookie that they have other teams successfully using the tool.

This is why we were questioning if a dot at the start of the domain is acceptable or not.

Comment: Can you please share the offending header in a bug report for OkHttp? It shouldn’t reject valid input!